# Delphi 10.3 CE on Android app development

Tags: android, delphi

I just installed Delphi 10.3 Community Edition and managed to locate the SDK/NDK needed for Android development.

I tried to `New` a `Multi-Device` Blank Application and put one Button, one Label in the canvas, and then a button-click event handler.

This project runs fine with Windows target. But when I tried to launch it under Android-64 platform:

1. It installs on my Android Emulator
2. It shows a splash logo
3. It quits, with no further interface.

Please help.

Comment: Add 'Firemonkey' to your tags.

Comment: Assuming your device has Android 10 or higher, you need to refer to: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27218?focusedCommentId=88179&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-88179